# Consulta SQL dentro de outra consulta

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sintaxe

Estou realizando um update no banco de dados, só que ele precisa pegar o último ID que foi gravado. Onde tem o `where` posso colocar outro comando dentro?

Desta forma:

```
$sql = mysqli_query($conexao, "UPDATE cadastro set
                                    nome_aluno = '$nome',
                                    data_nascimento = '$dataNasc',
                                    sexo = '$sexo', 
                                    celular = '$numcel',
                                    telefone = '$numtel',
                                    endereco = '$endereco',
                                    numero = '$numres',
                                    uf = '$uf',
                                    rg = '$rg',
                                    prontuario = '$prontuario',
                                    data_validade = '$datavalidade',
                                    curso = '$curso',
                                    semestre = '$semestre',
                                    periodo = '$periodo',
                                    email = '$email',
                                    senha = '$senha'
                                    where id = "$sql = "SELECT MAX(id) FROM cadastro");
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Pode mas tem um errinho de sintaxe aí, não use a variável do PHP nela (olha a última linha):

```
$sql = mysqli_query($conexao, "UPDATE cadastro set
                                nome_aluno = '$nome',
                                data_nascimento = '$dataNasc',
                                sexo = '$sexo', 
                                celular = '$numcel',
                                telefone = '$numtel',
                                endereco = '$endereco',
                                numero = '$numres',
                                uf = '$uf',
                                rg = '$rg',
                                prontuario = '$prontuario',
                                data_validade = '$datavalidade',
                                curso = '$curso',
                                semestre = '$semestre',
                                periodo = '$periodo',
                                email = '$email',
                                senha = '$senha'
                                where id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM cadastro));
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Database/Update2.php).